# Memory leaks in a simple class default constructor

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, mingw, googletest, dr-memory

The story is I got a couple `SEGFAULT`s - so I tested my program with Dr. Memory and got tons of memory leak messages involving the default constructor of the following class:

```
struct Colour {
    Colour()
        : value (0) {}   /** LINE 7 **/
    Colour (l_uint8 r, l_uint8 g, l_uint8 b)
        : value (r << L_RED_SHIFT | g << L_GREEN_SHIFT | b << L_BLUE_SHIFT) {}
    Colour (l_uint32 val)
        : value (val) {}

    l_uint32 value;

    l_uint8 r() { return value >> L_RED_SHIFT & 255; }
    l_uint8 g() { return value >> L_GREEN_SHIFT & 255; }
    l_uint8 b() { return value >> L_BLUE_SHIFT & 255; }

    void r (l_uint8 val) { value = (value & 0x00ffffff) | (val << L_RED_SHIFT); }
    void g (l_uint8 val) { value = (value & 0xff00ffff) | (val << L_GREEN_SHIFT); }
    void b (l_uint8 val) { value = (value & 0xffff00ff) | (val << L_BLUE_SHIFT); }
};
```

What can be wrong with it?!

Samples from Dr.Memory's summary:
First go such warnings:

```
Error #3: UNADDRESSABLE ACCESS beyond heap bounds: reading 0x0250090e-0x02500910 2 byte(s) within 0x02500900-0x02500910
# 0 nvd3d9wrap.dll!setDeviceHandle    +0x1710   (0x732ea060 <nvd3d9wrap.dll+0xa060>)
# 1 nvd3d9wrap.dll!CheckDXGIModule    +0x44f    (0x732e28a0 <nvd3d9wrap.dll+0x28a0>)
# 2 nvd3d9wrap.dll!GetNVDisplayW      +0x1b24   (0x732e4595 <nvd3d9wrap.dll+0x4595>)
# 3 __gcc_register_frame               [../OOP_Proj_W_Text_Rectification/colour.hpp:7]
# 4 register_frame_ctor                [../../../../../src/gcc-4.8.0/libgcc/config/i386/cygwin.S:184]
# 5 __tmainCRTStartup                  [../OOP_Proj_W_Text_Rectification/colour.hpp:7]
# 6 KERNEL32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk  +0x11     (0x777533aa <KERNEL32.dll+0x133aa>)
Note: @0:00:00.286 in thread 6876
Note: refers to 0 byte(s) beyond last valid byte in prior malloc
Note: prev lower malloc:  0x025008e8-0x0250090e
Note: instruction: movdqu (%edx) -> %xmm1
```

Then the leak messages:

```
Error #66: LEAK 188 direct bytes 0x031e00f8-0x031e01b4 + 0 indirect bytes
# 0 replace_operator_new                                                  [d:\drmemory_package\common\alloc_replace.c:2609]
# 1 testing::Message::Message                                             [../../../mingw48_32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/include/c++/googletest/src/gtest.cc:946]
# 2 testing::internal::FlagToEnvVar                                       [../../../mingw48_32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/include/c++/googletest/src/gtest-port.cc:1118]
# 3 testing::internal::BoolFromGTestEnv                                   [../../../mingw48_32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/include/c++/googletest/src/gtest-port.cc:1177]
# 4 __static_initialization_and_destruction_0                             [../../../mingw48_32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/include/c++/googletest/src/gtest.cc:202]
# 5 _GLOBAL__sub_I__ZN7testing8internal17kStackTraceMarkerE               [../../../mingw48_32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/include/c++/googletest/src/gtest-typed-test.cc:118]
# 6 __tmainCRTStartup                                                     [../OOP_Proj_W_Text_Rectification/colour.hpp:7]
# 7 KERNEL32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk                                     +0x11     (0x777533aa <KERNEL32.dll+0x133aa>)
```

UPD: the usage of the struct

1) As a return value

```
Colour Image::getPixel (size_t x, size_t y) const {
    Colour c;
    pixGetPixel (data, x, y, &(c.value));   // A method from Leptonica
    return c;
}
```

2) As a const reference method argument

3) As a storage for the function's return value

```
Colour c = getPixel (x, y)
```

Comment: post how you use the Colour struct

Comment: There has to be more to it than what you're posting.  You have a class `Image` being used, meaning there is an instance or instances being created somewhere (unless `getPixel` is a static member function).  If those instances are dynamically allocated and never deallocated, then that could be the source of memory leaks.  BTW, there isn't anything wrong with the `Colour` struct internally that would cause a memory leak, as it doesn't do dynamic memory allocation and has correct copy semantics.  It has to be a creation / destruction issue somewhere in your code of either `Image` and/or `Colour`.

Comment: Do I have to explicitly destroy the `Colours` despite none of them was allocated using `new`? I thought the runtime handles that

Comment: Do you still have he seg fault?   If so fox that first.  Otherwise, any object you create will be qualified as a leak when the program suddenly stops.

Comment: I tried the destructors, but the amounts of leaks (as well as of errors) did not change. Yet, the `SEGFAULT` has gone by itself for now

Comment: Please provide a minimal complete example that replicates the behavior your describe.

Comment: Error 3 reports about access beyond heap bounds. Unless Colour struct was created dynamically there is nothing in error related to Colour. The `pixGetPixel` seems like has pointer as one of parameters... I would check there probably 1st. Anyway more code would be helpful.

Comment: @Alex So you don't use `new` anywhere in your program?  Where do the instances of `Image` come from?  And again, `Colour` by itself does not cause a memory leak.  What would cause a memory leak is if `Colour` is a member of a class or struct that you've dynamically allocated, and your code does not deallocate that instance of the struct / class.